# /etc/php.ini is not loaded by php-cli or php-sapi

Tags: php

Strangely PHP 7.4.30 doesn't load `/etc/php.ini` !
I've compile it on AlmaLinux 8.6 to load it from there :

```
$ php -i | fgrep "Configure Command"
Configure Command =>  './configure' [...] '--with-apxs2' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--sysconfdir=/etc'
```

But instead it tries to load `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` that doesn't exist. I don't want to symlink it to `/etc/php.ini`.

```
$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

`--prefix` is not set, so it defaults to `/usr/local`.
If I force to load it by PHP-CLI of course it loads it and it doesn't find any errors  :

```
$ php --ini -c /etc/php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Same problem with SAPI version powered by Apache httpd 2.4 :

```
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>
```

Displays : `Loaded php.ini: /usr/local/lib/php.ini` which doesn't exist.